# How to prove a sequence is not converge uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis

Given a sequence of functions $(f_n)$ with  $f_n:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $f_n(x)=\dfrac{2nx(1+nx^2)}{n^2x^2+2}$. I proved that $(f_n)$ converges to $f:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=2x$. But, I can not prove that $(f_n)$ is not converge uniformly to $f$. Any suggestions for it ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If the convergence is uniform then $|f_n(x_n)-f(x)|$ must tend to for any sequence $(x_n)$. Put $x_n =\frac 1n$ to see that this is not satisfied.

Comment: Pardon me for this question. How do you solve these problems so quickly?

Comment: If you had spent over 50 years in Math you also would have done it equally quickly :-).

Comment: This is the 3rd problem (today) on SE which I was working on and you gave an excellent answer so quickly. Anyway thanks.

Comment: Thank you Kavi Rama Murthy and Gune. I have solved this problem with for every natural numer $k$, take $n_k=k+2$ and $x_k=\dfrac{1}{k+2}$.